# Is this the first riddle?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, english

> Ten million pies in a year
>   Or so it seems to my ear.
>   I'm around when you want more,
>   But the smallest sliver is in store.
>   I'm here if you want to fight.
>   Silver is a lovely sight.
>   I approve: I'm sure you agree.
>   I'm quick, but can't win, you see?

Who am I?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You seem like a

> Second

Ten million pies in a year Or so it seems to my ear.

> There are $3600 \times 24 \times 365  = 31536000$ in a non-leap year which is close to $10 000 000 \pi$

I'm around when you want more, But the smallest sliver is in store.

> Seconds are another helping of a food course.
>
>  A second piece of pie may mean a slice of angle $\frac{1}{3600}^\circ$ which is a small sliver.

I'm here if you want to fight.

> A second is a backup stand-in in a boxing match or duel.

Silver is a lovely sight.

> Silver is the medal for second place.

I approve: I'm sure you agree.

> To second is to approve a motion or  nomination.

I'm quick, but can't win, you see?

> Second position is highly placed in a race but not the winner.

The title: Is this the first riddle?

> No, but it may be second.

Comment: Wow! What a fantastic catch and explanation :) +1 Nice riddle as well.

Comment: Great answer. Well done. Maybe we can call it Tom's Riddle? I'll give other answerers (and you) a little more time to opine on the fourth line. But otherwise, you nailed it!

Comment: 4th line, possibly: the smallest sliver is a rot13(frpbaq unaq), which with store gives a rot13 (frpbaq-unaq fgber)?

Comment: That's pretty good, @Rubio, but it's much more obvious than that. The store is mainly to rhyme. Incidentally, I had the cryptic tag because rot13(cvr fbhaqf yvxr cv (urapr gur gb zl rne)). That's definitely a mainstay of cryptic crosswords I do... I defer to your superior reputation. Just curious.

Comment: @DrXorile We sometimes, only partly in jest, refer to things that share aspects of cryptic-clues but are not actually cryptic-clues themselves, as "cryptical clues" - I think yours qualifies.  The actual [tag:cryptic-clues] tag is intended to mark puzzles that have full, formal cryptic clues in them, which this does not.  There's no tag for "cryptical clues" as such, but they often count as [tag:wordplay].  This puzzle has that aplenty, so the wordplay tag seems fitting.

Comment: The fourth has me in a tangle,
I will try a tiny angle,
If it's not about this degree, 
you can call it tomfoolery.

Answer (score 2):

**Alternate answer:** *[non competing]*

> A knife in a gunfight / cake shop

Ten million pies in a year
Or so it seems to my ear

> Used to cut fools / pies every year

I'm around when you want more

> It would be tempting to pick up your knife if you were an aggressive vigilante who wanted to take on gun wielding fiends / also around when you want more cake

But the smallest sliver is in store

> A cut from a knife will usually be a small sliver and not a gaping wound / if you're getting a sample cake you get a tiny sliver

I'm here if you want to fight

> ;) ;) ;) / fighting the person who served you for more cake

Silver is a lovely sight

> The glint of the blade in the light

I approve: I'm sure you agree

> Again catering to the aggressive vigilante tenancy's / overeating is always approved by knife

I'm quick, but can't win, you see?

> Well you did bring a knife to a gun fight / you can't win against eating food and getting fat, but it's so quick to fall down that hole